# Four variations of jQuery ready() -- what's the difference?

Tags: jquery, dom, document-ready

I've seen four different ways to tell jQuery to execute a function when the document is ready. Are these all equivalent?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('$(document).ready()');
});  

$().ready(function () {
  alert('$().ready()');
}); 

$(function () {
  alert('$()');
});     

jQuery(function ($) {
  alert('jQuery()');
});
```

Comment: btw, i think `$(window).ready(...)` works too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference.

`$` is the same as `jQuery`. If you view the unminified source, you will see `var $ = jQuery = ...` or something to that effect.

The `jQuery` function checks the type of it's parameter, if it is a function, it treats it the same as `$(document).ready(...)`

Calling `jQuery` without a parameter defaults to using `document`. So `$()` and `$(document)` are identical. Try it in Firebug.

Comment: This doesn't explain the second one

Comment: crap, i thought i got them all. hold on.

Comment: Is it defaulting to using document or is it a result of jQuery being returned via chaining after passing no args?

Comment: Since you pointed it out, is there a difference between $(window).ready() and $(document).ready()?

Comment: @David: run `$()` in firebug, you will see that the result is jQuery with 1 element--`document`.

Comment: @Patrick: to my knowledge, there is no effective difference if used consistently. The only thing that I think that could change is the order of the ready event, due to propagation. I'd have to test it to be sure.

Comment: I see! Oh and re $(window).ready and $(document).ready: I wonder if $(window) might wait for images to be loaded etc, cos $(document).ready fires as soon as the DOM is ready (before images etc)

Comment: @David: that would certainly make sense to me if that were the case.

Comment: From browsing the source, it seems it all boils down to "this.call( document, jQuery )" [line 2912 in 1.3.1] meaning the anonymous function is passed the JQuery object and executed in the context of document. $(window).ready(), $(document).ready(), and even ('#bogus_selector').ready() all do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

re: Geroge IV's comments regarding $() == $(document) its correct. From the unminified source (init is what get called internally):

```
init: function( selector, context ) {
    // Make sure that a selection was provided
    selector = selector || document;
```

Also from source, to back up previous conversations:

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
    // Shortcut for document ready
    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) )
        return jQuery( document ).ready( selector );
```

this should be community wiki.  I've always been interested in the inner workings of jquery, now I've had an excuse to start looking :-)

Comment: Ah don't know how to do that or if I can, but i've opened one up linking to this :-D

Answer (score 1):

Also it **should be mentioned**, that symbol that you pass to function will be use inside the function. For example:

```
$(function(jQuery) {
   // now I can use jQuery instead $
   jQuery("body").append("<div></div>"); // adds div to the end of body element
});
```

if you want use $ - you can leave function's param in **this** situation empty

The real example you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/yura_syedin/BNgd4/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one - starts like this...

```
(function (jQuery) {
```

then to finish...

```
})(jQuery);
```

An example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/C2qZw/23/